# Android Push notification (slow)

Tags: android, performance, time, notifications, push-notification

I have IIS server and send Notification with GoogleCloudMessaging to phone. It takes about 10 minutes to receive the message on android device. It's huge time form my project. do you know how decrease the time ?

That is server C# code (Using PushSharp)

var push = new PushBroker();

```
        //Wire up the events for all the services that the broker registers
        /*NotificationSent s = new NotificationSent()
        push.OnNotificationSent += "NotificationSent";
        push.OnChannelException += "ChannelException";
        push.OnServiceException += "ServiceException";
        push.OnNotificationFailed += "NotificationFailed";
        push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += "DeviceSubscriptionExpired";
        push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += "DeviceSubscriptionChanged";
        push.OnChannelCreated += "ChannelCreated";
        push.OnChannelDestroyed += "ChannelDestroyed";
        */

        push.RegisterGcmService(new GcmPushChannelSettings("MY API KEY"));

        push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().
            ForDeviceRegistrationId("PHONE REGISTRATION ID")
                              .WithJson(@"{""alert"":""Name !"",""badge"":7,""sound"":""sound.caf""}"));


        //Stop and wait for the queues to drains
        push.StopAllServices();
```

And This Is my receiver,

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}
```

}

Comment: That depends on what's causing the delay. If it's a network issue (as in, low network coverage), your only solution is to either wait to get it or connect to a better network. It could also be your server not immediately sending the push message. Basically, it can be a ton of different things, and without your code we have no idea what your problem is (or even if there is one, or if you just have a fundamental misunderstanding of networking, which I'm not saying is the case...)

Comment: @Guardanis  I've updated the code , see above

Comment: So now the question becomes: Does "QueueNotification()" cause it to wait, or does it immediately send the Push?

Comment: @Guardanis  
while debuging server code, it immediately goes to next line -  push.StopAllServices();

and after this, on my Android app it enters OnReceive method after 7 - 10 minutes :(

Comment: Just because it goes to the next line doesn't mean it's automatically sending. That line is adding it to a queue, which means it's probably running on a completely separate pooling thread which will send it at intervals determined by your server and its settings.

Comment: @Guardanis, Ok and how and where can I change the settings ?

Comment: Maybe you should ask the people who built the library. Or try looking through the code yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was  that many wifi routers close connection to server and the device needs time to reconnect to Google server after wifi closes connection.

The solution is to send heartbeat packages every 3-4 minutes to have permanent connection.